# Is there any way to stop the Upgrade-SPSite as it is taking long time to complete?

Tags: 2013, upgrade

Can i stop Upgrade-SPSite process as it is taking long time to execute and got stuck. The upgrade log file is not getting updated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what the size of database?

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to stop the Upgrade-process, becuase if you some why stop it, it can damage your site collections as they are upgrading process.

Upgrade timing depends upon couple of things.

- Server resources( CPU and RAM)
- SQL Server resources
- How big the database is
- how big the site collection is and how complex its structure.
- how many subwebs in the site collections also slow down the process.

Comment: looks like a complex site structure with huge amount of data